# Not able to Import Selenium2Library in a robot file

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Below image is the sample reference of the robot code I have written. I have imported Selenium2Library, there were no errors but in test case section of Robot framework its not getting recognized.

[Sample Robot Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZSog.png)

clearly, under settings section, we see that the library selenium2library is not being recognized?

Comment: what are the plugins that are being installed?

Comment: You need to mention that the problem is specific to your editor.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have installed the "robotframework-selenium2library". if not, please use the following pip command

```
pip install robotframework-selenium2library
```

I have referred your image and I could see there is a syntax error while you import a library.

In Robot test file settings sections, while importing a library the syntax should be

```
Library  YouDesiredLibrary
```

In this case it is

```
Library  Selenium2Library
```

Once you are done with all the imports you have the define any variables you want to use  for your test case which you have done correctly.

In the test cases Table/section

You need to call open the URL, you need to user [Open Browser](https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Open%20Browser) keyword with browser name and URL ans arguments

Please try this and let me know.

Comment: Hi, I tried the same thing you have suggested but I still see the same issue persisting

Comment: Ok, also try to install robotframework-selenium and robotframework-seleniumLibrary then try to execute you test. Make sure you have imported a right library.

Comment: Hello All, I came across this Plugin "Intellibot@SeleniumLibrary Patched" I installed it and then Library SeleniumLibrary began to be recognised. Thanks for your inputs guys.